# Finding the convergence radius of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n! x^{n!}$

Tags: calculus

I need help finding the covergence radius of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n! x^{n!}$ .

The factorials make me think that I need to use derivatives/ integrals but I don't quite know how.

I'd love any help, thanks.

Comment: Two hints: for $x\gt 0$, your series is bounded above by $\sum_n nx^n$ (why?); for $x\gt 1$, it's bounded from below by $\sum_nx^n$ (again, why?).

Answer (score 3):

It is simpler than that. First you have :

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n! x^{n!}\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n}$$

Hence the radius of convergence of the serie on the left is $\geq 1$ and :

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}n!\text{ does not converge when } N \text{ goes to infinity} $$

Hence the radius of convergence is $\leq 1$.

Comment: How did you arrive at the first series inequality?